# How to create dynamic columns with column name and value using java

Tags: java, spring, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

I tried to generate a report using the [dynamic-japer] I have a doubt, how should I achieve dynamic columns based on the data source or resultset I have, is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

try to put the column in details part and change the page format " print order " horizental

Comment: can you please provide some code I didn't understand your answer

Comment: Right click on details part then click on Page format
Then there is box for column change print order to horizontal

Comment: thanks for time, but I need java only to create reports